# Sintaxis en Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Tengo un error de sintaxis al hacer una Consulta en Access, me arroja el error de  Error de sintaxis(falta operador) en la consulta 'CAST(SUM(muertes) AS FLOAT)/ SUM(casos) * 1000'

```
SELECT paises_territorios,
CAST (SUM(muertes) AS FLOAT) / SUM(casos) * 1000
FROM covid_data
GROUP BY paises_territorios
HAVING población_2018 > 30000000;
```

Esta es la consulta que realizo, les anexo como es mi tabla

[image]

[image: Este es el error que me aparece]

Comment: Podrías agregar el error que obtienes?

Comment: En tu SQL pones `población_2018` con tilde, pero en tu tabla se llama `POBLACIÓN_2018` sin tilde. ¿Podría ser eso?

Comment: @BetaM  Añado el error a la pregunta

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes   Ya modifique eso también, no me había percatado pero tampoco era eso

Comment: No uses `CAST()`.